# Use of find vs. at in map / unordered_map

Tags: c++, exception, containers

The following shows two ways of looking up an element of an `unordered_map`, and raising some error condition if the element of the desired key does not exist. They essentially do the same thing. Is there reason to prefer one over the other, or is it simply a matter of style?

```
void foo()
{
    unordered_map<string, int> lookup;

    // Method 1. Lookup using find.
    const auto i = lookup.find("myKey");
    if (i == lookup.end()) {
        // Some error condition...
    }
    else {
        // Do something with i...
    }

    // Method 2. Lookup using try / catch.
    try {
        const auto& ele = lookup.at("myKey");
        // Do something with ele...
    }
    catch (out_of_range& e) {
        // Some error condition...
    }
}
```

Comment: In a general manner, you should rather think of the intent behind these methods rather than what they can actually do - `find` is like *"I am looking for something that **may be there**."* while `at` is more *"I am looking for something that **must be there**."*. If `find` does not find the item, you know what to do (because you expected it may not find it), if `at` does not find it, you are lost because this should have never happened (basically).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I would never use exceptions for something like that. Exceptions are for the truly exceptional. Their power lies in allowing you to write code without constant local error checking. But not finding an element in a container is not (usually) an error, its just one of two possibilities.

As a rule I would say use exceptions if not finding the element means you have to abort the entire function/operation/subsystem. Don't use it to check individual statement results.

Comment: I take your point and agree that exception handling should not be used for general control flow. It could, however, be a precondition that an element of the specified key exists within the map, i.e. a failed lookup indicates a bug within the application, which could be considered an exceptional scenario.

Comment: @Frank Yes, indeed. My final sentence was intended to convey something along those lines.

Comment: I tend to agree with you. I prefer the use of `find` in this situation. The exception of Method 2 is handled within the same function and the `else` block of Method 1 achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

These methods have completely different return values, thus they are useful in different situations.

For example, if you need the value itself, you may use both of them, as you may easily obtain the value from the iterator. But you cannot do the opposite: `at` returns a value reference, which cannot be "converted" to an iterator for O(1) time. The only way to "get" iterator from value reference is to iterate over the map using i.e. `find`. So if you need a value, call `at`, and if you need an iterator, call `find`. Also `at` should be faster as it does not handle intermediate iterator object and does not require dereference operator call.

Another concern is exception availability. Exceptions may be forbidden by the project's code style for some reason, or even disabled by compiler flags. In this case using `find` is the only option.

Comment: So there is an overhead in the intermediate iterator object, but exception handling comes with its own overheads. I guess that in the end it will be down to how a compiler optimises for these situations.

Answer (score 2):

As exception handling imply restrictions to the optimizer, the second method results - in most cases - to larger binaries. In addition, exception handling is not desired (even disabled) on/in some systems.

In case you are developing a library potentially to be used by others, prefer the first method.